# Communicating between Android phone and Computer

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an android app which can access my computer's screen and file directory structure over the network.

A simple way would be to create a server running on my computer's localhost and to access it using my smartphone. But one question here is, would I be able to create a native Android app to access this, or would I be restricted to the browser?

Any other methods of achieving this that you would recommend? Maybe a way to SSH from my phone to my Ubuntu PC? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using TCP Socket. Example: Create an application on PC use C# language, open port 8888 (ex: 192.168.1.200:8888). Then create an android app connect to 192.168.1.200:8888. OK. Some functions the same with FileZilla. When Android app sent command 'C:\ ls' to PC app. It returns a list directories in C:\ and send back again android app...When user double click in a directory (ex: Users) in android app, it will sent command 'cd Users' to PC app...

Hope it help you